# Comparing sub items from a list of lists

Tags: python

I,ve 2 lists:

```
l = [['red','a1',1],['red','a2',1],['blue','a3',1],['yellow','a4',1]]
```

and

```
k = [['red','a2',1],['blue','a3',1],['yellow','a4',1]]
```

so I want to return something like this:

```
result = [0, 1, 1, 1]
```

Sorry I´ve to practice list comprehension a little more!!

my function:

```
def vectors(doc1,doc2,consulta):
    res=[]
    r = doc1 + doc2 + consulta
    for e in r:
        for i in doc1:
            if i[0] == e[0]:
                i[2] = i[2] + 1
        else:
            i[2] = 0
    return res.append(i[2])
```

The order doesn´t matter, the important thing is the comparison.

Best Regards!

Comment: The code must include multiplicty, the vector must be the times that "l" appears in "k". Should I use a counter for that?

Answer (score 3):

Inefficient but easy:

```
result = [x in k for x in l]
```

Efficient (for large `k`) but slightly more complicated:

```
kset = set(tuple(x) for x in k)
result = [tuple(x) in kset for x in l]
```

Comment: Also, I need to consider the times the elements of l appears in k, what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

```
>>> result = [1 if li in k else 0 for li in l]
>>> result
[0, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Also, I need to consider the times the elements of l appears in k, what can I do?